# Insertar dato de tipo timestamp en base de datos PostgreSQL

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

¿Cómo puedo insertar la fecha y hora en una base de datos de *PostgreSQL* donde el campo es de tipo *timestamp*?

Probé la siguiente consulta en *PostgreSQL*, pero da un error de que la fecha no es compatible con *timestamp*:

Código:

```
insert into tabla (nombre, ctime, mtime) values ('pepe', '2017-05-2', '2017-05-2')
```

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado amplia. Por favor, especifica un poco más (si es manualmente, con que lenguaje de programación), pon las consultas o código que hayas intentado, etc.

Comment: La sección `8.1.5.3` de la [documentación de timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) seguramente también te sea de mucha utilidad

Comment: Quien inserta datos directamente a la BD es **responsable** de enviarle los datos correctamente. Las dos fechas están **mal** formadas. ¿Quizá PG en realidad no sabe si **¿es 2 de mayo o 20 de mayo?**, pues falta un cero, delante o detrás... y decide arrojarte un error? Si es desde un programa, quien escribió el programa es **responsable** de validar los datos, para que **nunca** se envíen a la  BD datos incorrectos o mal formados. [Sobre timestamp puedes leer esto](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-timestamp/).

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, la idea es que tengo que insertar la fecha en que ocurre un evento determinado, y el tipo de dato que requiere la base de datos dice timestamp without time zone

Answer (score 0):

Hablas de "insertar fecha y hora" pero en tu ejemplo es solo una fecha.
De todas maneras, normalmente ese formato debería funcionar.

Para asegurarte, basta que pruebes hacer un cast, sin necesidad de usar ninguna tabla:

Ej:

```
select  '2017-05-2'::timestamp;
      timestamp
---------------------
 2017-05-02 00:00:00
```

En realidad, el formato de fecha que Postgresql emite (y acepta) depende de un parámetro de configuración [DATESTYLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE)

Por defecto, el formato `ISO` es aceptado (y recomendado). El formato de fechas con ISO es AÑO-MES-DIA.

Para saber cual es tu datestyle:

```
show datestyle;
 DateStyle
-----------
 ISO, MDY
```

Comment: En realidad lo que necesito es insertar algo como esto '2017-05-07 21:50:02', para ello me encontre la variable LOCALTIMESTAMP pero devuelve este resultado '2017-05-07 21:50:02.43'. Imagino que el ultimo valor sea algo como las milésimas de segundos o algo así pero no necesito insertarlo en la tabla. Tienes alguna idea de cómo obviar ese valor. Saludos

Comment: Probaste leer mi respuesta? Probaste hacer lo que te puse en primer codigo y en el segundo?

Comment: Sí, lo del datestyle me devuelve ISO y MDY (los dos), el problema es que no logro llevar la fecha actual al formato '2017-05-07 22:37:14' para poder insertarlo. No entiendo todavía como podría ayudarme el tema del datestyle ...??

Comment: Probaste hacer `select  '2017-05-07 21:50:02'::timestamp;` ? Te tira error o no? Si no, entonces ese string es una entrada valida para un timestamp

Comment: Eso si lo probé y no da error, ahora lo que me pregunto es como llevar la fecha y hora actual a string con el formato 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss para poder insertarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar funciones de fecha/hora de postgreSQL, por ejemplo:

```
to_timestamp(text, text)

insert into tabla (nombre, ctime, mtime) 
values ('pepe',
to_timestamp('02 May 2017', 'DD Mon YYYY'), 
to_timestamp('02 May 2017', 'DD Mon YYYY')
);
```

Aquí tienes más información sobre las funciones/fecha hora: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html